# Jaggedly shaded faces and other funkiness

Tags: mesh

I'm trying to combine two meshes together and am running into some really weird issues. My combined mesh has all these jaggedly shaded faces, vertices I can't select from certain angles and interrupted or dotted edge lines. What's going on? I already ran Merge Vertices By Distance and Flip Normals and the problem persists.

Please ignore the combination of tris and quads and how much of a mess the rest is (unless it has something to do with my issues), I'm intending to go in and fix the topology later once these issues are resolved.

[image: Close-up showing jagged shading and general funkiness]
[image: Shot of the entire model with same vertex selected as before]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience that usually happens when the viewport camera *Clip Start* and *Clip End* values (<kbd>N</kbd> *> View*) are too high or too low. They're not real geometry, just shading issues due to excess precision.

[image]